# .net Core View doesn't refresh/update the data

Tags: .net-core

On my page, I got a form that needs to be verified before saved.
For example,

Step 1- User enters a postcode and Boolean AddressVerified status is False and Click VERIFY button which is posting data to the Server,

Step 2- Server checks if AddressVerified is FALSE, then check the postcode, and if address verified sets AddressVerified status TRUE and returns the data back to the user.

Step 3- Now user click the Save buttons to send data back to the server.

Step 4- Server checks if AddressVerified == True saves data into database.

**ISSUE**
On Step 3, the AddressVerified was set TRUE by server, but the checkbox in the View still shows FALSE. I mean unchecked.

```
<input asp-for="AddressVerified"/>
```

DOM Doesn't update the "AddressVerified" status, unless the user click the checkBox.
I mean View keeps previous value on checkbox.

BUT when i check the Model, AddressVerified is set TRUE.

So What i did:

```
   @if (Model.AddressVerified)
   {
      <input asp-for="AddressVerified" checked />
   }
   else
   {
      <input asp-for="AddressVerified"/>                         
   }
```

I don't understand why View doesn't update the checkbox check status depending on Data with the following code

```
<input asp-for="AddressVerified"/>
```

Comment: do you have anything to update your website for example Ajax? If not, you need to add some JavaScript or something else to recheck that.

Comment: try:  <input type="checkbox"  asp-for="AddressVerified"  checked="checked" />

Comment: Hi Stuiter, I don't have any script code but when i check the Elements, i can see that checkbox value is false.

Comment: HI Nima, I just try and it is always ticked, even Data is false.

Comment: Can you post your view including Verify button pls? It is hard to understand how are trying to post

Comment: Hi Serge, it is late here now, but Monday morning I will create a simple project for you so  you can copy and paste your editor to test it.